# How to get the created_at in pivot table in laravel

Tags: laravel-5, pivot-table

Im confused how to get the `created_at` column in my `pivot` table. I have `exam_user` table with `created_at` and `updated_at` column. Now, I have this code in my view:

```
@if($exam->users()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->exists())
    {{ Auth::user()->assignments()->pivot->created_at }}
    <div class="alert alert-success">You have done with this exam.</div>
@else
```

Any idea for this?

Answer (score 22):

When setting up your relationships, you need to specify if that pivot table has timestamps.

```
 public function things() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Thing')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Edit:

try `Auth::user()->assignments()->first()->pivot->created_at`

Comment: try `Auth::user()->assignments()->first()->pivot->created_at`

Comment: Its just getting the first result. I want to get the current assignment using the current view